# Why did Francis shapeshifter leave the shape-shifter device behind?

Tags: fringe, shape-shifter

In Season 2 of Fringe (spoiler):

> Charlie Francis finds himself alone in a hospital boiler room with a shapeshifter in the form of a nurse. The shapeshifter kills Francis and takes his form. When the other agents arrive, he is standing over the body of the shapeshifter/nurse and the shifter device is in the nurse corpse!

Assuming that the shapeshifter had plenty of time to change the bodies, why he left the shifter device in the nurse corpse?

It makes no sense, he is stuck on Francis body because of this! Even if (somehow) the device is broken, why leave it there? It makes no sense to help his opponents by providing them this device for them to study.

Comment: I don't have a cite for it, but I'm fairly sure it's mentioned that the shapeshifter devices are specific to the individual. In other words, a shapeshifter can't just pick up any device, it has to be THEIR OWN device.

Comment: @JoeL. I don't think it's mentioned but implied when Shapeshifter Charlie meets another shapeshifter while looking for Newton's head. He says to Shapeshifter Charlie "You look like crap. You've been in that body for too long. I'd let borrow my device but it wouldn't work anyway".

Answer (score 5):

Two reasons:
1. He wanted the Fringe team to think that they had captured the shapeshifter successfully, and thus continue in his disguise.
2. He must have been planning on getting back the device once the nurse was taken away, but failed to do this.